# material-ui-next - Dynamically set palette color

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am using `"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.33"` for my project.
What I want to do is set **primary palette color** dynamically inside a react component (color will be fetched from some api).
Basically I want to override below:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: "some color from api" 
  },
})
```

Is there a way to set this in `componentDidMount` function of any component?

Reference: https://material-ui-next.com/

Comment: Have you figured this out yet ?  I too am in need of this feature.

Comment: @user1184205 check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I created a component that uses MuiThemeProvider and wrap my entire app around that component. Below is the structure of the component.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {withStyles} from 'material-ui/styles';
import * as colors from 'material-ui/colors';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export class ThemeWrapperComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(
        {
          palette: {
            primary: { main: **colorFromApi** },
          }
      )}>
        <div>
            { this.props.children }
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export const ThemeWrapper = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(ThemeWrapperComponent));
```

Below is how I wrapped my app around this component:

```
 <ThemeWrapper>
    <div>          
      <Routes/>
    </div>                
 </ThemeWrapper>
```

Now, whatever colour you are sending from the api gets applied to the whole theme. More customisation can be done based on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing exactly this.  Even got it working with WebMIDI using MIDI controller sliders and knobs just for fun.

[image]

The basic strategy is to use `createMuiTheme` and `ThemeProvider` and to store the theme in your application store (`context`, `state`, `redux`), etc.

```
class ThemeManager extends React.Component {
  getThemeJson = () => this.props.context.themeJson || defaultThemeJson

  componentDidMount () {
    const themeJson = this.getThemeJson()
    const theme = createMuiTheme(themeJson)
    this.props.setContext({ theme, themeJson })
  }

  render () {
    const { children, context } = this.props
    const theme = context.theme
    return theme
      ? <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
      : children
  }
}
```

https://github.com/platform9/pf9-ui-plugin/blob/master/src/app/ThemeManager.js

and then you simply update your application's state.

```
  handleImport = themeStr => {
    const themeJson = JSON.parse(themeStr)
    const theme = createMuiTheme(themeJson)
    this.props.setContext({ theme, themeJson })
  }
```

https://github.com/platform9/pf9-ui-plugin/blob/master/src/app/plugins/theme/components/ImportExportPanel.js#L17